# How to completely reload a Wordpress php template with google Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, reload, browser-cache

I know my Question was asked a few times before but i can't get rid of my problem:
Only if i'm working on Wordpress Sites my Browser (Google Chrome) needs a couple of reloads until it noticed that i did changes at some `php` template files. When I change for example my themes `css` Google Chrome immediately show the right results.

What i did so far was:

1. Disable cache (while DevTools is open)
2. Installed a Google Chrome extension (Click and Clean) to empty chache
3. cmd + shift + R

Anyone had same problem? 
no success so far, thankful for ideas and help

Comment: did that already also no success

Comment: Have you try to open it with other computer?

Comment: Did you install any cache-plugins or made settings about that yourself?
There are quite a lot of plugins that promise to speed up your wordpress and then save a lot of things in a server-side cache to reduce the loading-time. During development you should not use those plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press f12 and right click on reload icon  then select Empty cache and hard reload.Please Look following image

[image]

Comment: dont knew that but also needs some reloads

Comment: But single reload only